# Issue in passing multiple parameters in Batch file to remote shell script using Plink

Tags: linux, windows, shell, batch-file, putty

I am running a bat file from windows command line which calls a linux script to copy a file:

WIN_BATCH.bat content:

```
"C:\plink.exe" -ssh User@%1 -pw "pass123" "/u01/./LINUX_COPY_SCRIPT.sh %1"
```

LINUX_COPY_SCRIPT content as below:

```
sshpass -p "pass123" scp /u01/file_1.txt root@$1:/u01/file_1_Copy.txt
```

When I am running command from Win cmd as below, evereything is working fine, i.e.

Win command prompt:

```
C:\Scripts>WINbatch.bat 11.111.11.11
```

Message in CMD:

```
C:\Scripts>"C:\plink.exe" -ssh User@11.111.11.11 -pw "pass123" "/u01/./LINUX_COPY_SCRIPT.sh 11.111.11.11"
C:\Scripts>
```

And the file gets copied from "file_1.txt" to "file_1_Copy.txt"

Now comes the issue, if I modify my scripts as below:

WIN_BATCH.bat content:

```
"C:\plink.exe" -ssh User@%1 -pw "pass123" "/u01/./LINUX_COPY_SCRIPT.sh %2"
```

LINUX_COPY_SCRIPT content as below:

```
sshpass -p "pass123" scp /u01/file_1.txt root@$2:/u01/file_1_Copy.txt
```

and pass 2 parameter:

Win command prompt:

```
C:\Scripts>WINbatch.bat 11.111.11.11 11.111.11.11
```

I'm getting error:

```
C:\Scripts>"C:\plink.exe" -ssh User@11.111.11.11 -pw "pass123" "/u01/./LINUX_COPY_SCRIPT.sh 11.111.11.11"
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known
lost connection
C:\Scripts>
```

WHY ?? If you see the commands fired in both cases are same, as i am passing the same parameter.

HOW I CAN GET THIS WORKING ? The idea to pass multiple parameter because i want to copy file from one env to other at later stage.

I.e. once

```
C:\Scripts>WINbatch.bat 11.111.11.11 11.111.11.11
```

is working I'll be doing

```
C:\Scripts>WINbatch.bat 11.111.11.11 11.111.11.12
```

Where "11.111.11.11" and "11.111.11.12" are ip of 2 systems.

Comment: Why not install Cygwin and write real shell scripts instead of crummy DOS bat files?

Comment: Yeah, but i cant install Cygwin, so need to figure out something which i have...

Comment: Also I don't see any mistake in this approach, passing multiple parameters is absolutely fine in windows batch file but not sure whats the issue here, even when i am using the same parameter twice..

Comment: From the batch you only pass one argument `%2` so the shell script can't access `$2` as it is not present.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me on this issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing only one argument to `LINUX_COPY_SCRIPT.sh`:

```
"C:\plink.exe" -ssh User@%1 -pw "pass123" "/u01/./LINUX_COPY_SCRIPT.sh %2"
```

But you are trying to use second argument (`$2`) in the shell script:

```
sshpass -p "pass123" scp /u01/file_1.txt root@$2:/u01/file_1_Copy.txt
```

It should be `$1`:

```
sshpass -p "pass123" scp /u01/file_1.txt root@$1:/u01/file_1_Copy.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, This make sense